# How to prevent timer reset using pushViewController method?

Tags: ios, swift, timer, viewcontroller

I'm trying to keep a timer running even if I switch view controllers. I played around with the Singleton architecture, but I don't quite get it. Pushing a new view controller seems a little easier, but when I call the below method, the view controller that is pushed is blank (doesn't look like the view controller that I created in Storyboards). The timer view controller that I'm trying to push is also the second view controller, if that changes anything.

```
@objc func timerPressed() {
        let timerVC = TimerViewController()
        navigationController?.pushViewController(timerVC, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to load it from storyboard

```
let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VCName") as! TimerViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(timerVC, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your problem is that your controller is blank or that the timer resets. Anyway, in case that you want to keep the time in the memory and not deallocate upon navigating somewhere else I recommend you this.

Create some kind of `Constants` class which will have a shared param inside.

It could look like this:

```swift
class AppConstants {
    static let shared = AppConstants()
    var timer: Timer?
}
```

And do whatever you were doing with the timer here accessing it via the shared param.

`AppConstants.shared.timer ...`

Answer (score 0):

There are different parts to your question. Sh_Khan told you what was wrong with the way you were loading your view controller (simply invoking a view controller’s init method does not load it’s view hierarchy. Typically you will define your view controller’s views in a storyboard, so you need to instantiate it from that storyboard.)

That doesn’t answer the question of how to manage a timer however. A singleton is a good way to go if you want your timer to be global instead of being tied to a particular view controller.

Post the code that you used to create your singleton and we can help you with that.

### Edit: Updated to give the TimeManager a delegate:

The idea is pretty simple. Something like this:

```
protocol TimeManagerDelegate {
    func timerDidFire()
}

class TimerManager {
    static let sharedTimerManager = TimerManager()
    weak var delegate: TimeManagerDelegate?

    //methods/vars to manage a shared timer.
    func handleTimer(timer: Timer) {
       //Put your housekeeping code to manage the timer here

       //Now tell our delegate (if any) that the timer has updated.
       //Note the "optional chaining" syntax with the `?`. That means that
       //If `delegate` == nil, it doesn't do anything.
       delegate?.timerDidFire() //Send a message to the delegate, if there is one.
    }
}
```

And then in your view controller:

```
//Declare that the view controller conforms to the TimeManagerDelegate protocol
class SomeViewController: UIViewController, TimeManagerDelegate {

    //This is the function that gets called on the current delegate
    func timerDidFire() {
       //Update my clock label (or whatever I need to do in response to a timer update.)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear() {
        super.viewWillAppear()
        //Since this view controller is appearing, make it the TimeManager's delegate.
        sharedTimerManager.delegate = self
    }
```

Comment: cool, I got it to work! The only problem is that when I switch between the view controllers, the default label for my clock is displayed, as opposed to the time that's currently ticking. Any ways around that?

Comment: What do you want to happen? Do you want any of your view controllers to display the current time? Can there be multiple view controllers in your view controller stack at the same time that need to be updated?

Comment: I'd say give your TimerManager singleton a weak delegate property with a `timerDidFire()` method. In each view controller's viewWillAppear method, execute `sharedTimerManager.delegate = self`. In the TimerManager, when the timer fires, execute `delegate?.timerDidFire()`. In the view controller, conform to the protocol, and have your `timerDidFire()` method update the clock label.

Comment: See the edit to my answer. I describe how to set up the TimeManager to take a delegate that gets notified when the timer updates.

Comment: Ahh, okay I see what the problem is. I think you're misunderstanding my problem... sorry! Let me try to clarify! So using the singleton class, my timer continues running even when I switch view controllers, however, the label of my clock will reset if I switch view controllers (resets to the default text that I put in). Do you know how to address that? I'm not sure if using delegates will, as I don't want to only update the clock's label, but I want to keep it running.

Comment: Never mind! Fixed it :) Just have to invalidate and run the timer again in viewWillAppear() sorry about the mass comments, thanks so much!